# Is there a way to pass different (but specific) types of objects in same method and have different ways to handle based on the type of object

Tags: java, selenium, oop, polymorphism

I have to write a method that will **click on an element present on the web page**.
The problem is I can have **only either of the two types of objects in my method** i.e. either a 'WebElement' object or a 'By' object. So, in order to do that I have to write repetitive lines of code for the two overloaded methods as shown below:

```
    public void clickElement(WebElement element) {
        Line 1;
        Line 2;
        element.click();
        Line 3;
    }
    
    public void clickElement(By locator) {
        Line 1;
        Line 2;
        driver.findElement(locator).click();
        Line 3;
    }
```

**Is it possible to write only one method which is can take only one of either two types of object and behave accordingly?** Something like this:

```
public void clickElement(WebElement element **OR** By locator) {
        Line 1;
        Line 2;
        element.click; **OR** driver.findElement(locator).click();
        Line 3;
    }

Let me know if my question needs more clarification or inputs.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use selenium. Based on your code, I am assuming `driver.findElement()` returns `WebElement`, and Line 1, 2, 3 is exactly the same in both methods. If this is the case, the best way I can think of to implement this is as follows.

```
    public void clickElement(WebElement element) {
        Line 1;
        Line 2;
        element.click();
        Line 3;
    }
    
    public void clickElement(By locator) {
        clickElement(driver.findElement(locator));
    }
```

By doing so, we can maximize code reuse while preserving the method signature which enforces the type of class that can be passed to these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at java generics, specifically generic methods - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html